# Programmatically save one/any post

Tags: import, save-post, cron

I am using WP All import in order to import listings in a website. Everything works well except displaying all listings in a map. If i edit any listing, and then click Update (without making any changes at all), all listings are then displayed correctly. So i am thinking, can i create a cron job that will edit and save one post? It doesn't have to do any changes. It could be a draft one that it won't be displayed in the frond end.

Thank you for your time.